# Using locally a tensorflow model from Google AutoML Tabular

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

I want to use my trained tensorflow model from Google VertexAI AutoML for tabular data locally but I don't understand the documentation and how to pass the input into my model to get the prediction into a backtesting module (so I don't want to deploy it yet).
The model is stored in a directory under saved_model.pb alongside with 3 directories : variables, assets, assets.extra

Model was trained with:

```
tensorflow: "2.8.0"
struct2tensor: "0.39.0"
tensorflow-addons: "0.16.1"
```

Some more info i got from my python code:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(path)
print(list(model.signatures.keys()))
infer = model.signatures["serving_default"]
print(infer.structured_outputs)
```

Output:

> ['serving_default']

> {'classes': <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_25:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=string>, 'scores': <tf.Tensor 'truediv:0' shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32>}

I trained on a tabular data, a pandas DataFrame with 14 features and the target column.
How can I pass my 14 column vector as input of my model ? I heard it might be possible also to repackage the saved_model.pb into a keras model, but the inference is less optimized, but I am ready to go that way.

So far I tried these references from official doc:

https://github.com/Lornatang/TensorFlow2-tutorials/blob/master/guide/serialization/saved_model.py

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

I didn't find any VertexAI documentation to deploy locally without a docker container to serve the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load the trained model directly using TensorFlow - you must use the AutoML Tables export model via the model server container image as described on the [Export AutoML Models](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-model-tabular#export) documentation.

So to local experimentation, I think the best way out is spinning the model-server container on your local machine and testing.

Comment: If it runs in docker, it should run locally somehow, so far I could load the model, but I was not able to use it as I don't understand how to use the signature of it and to use this "scores" function and give my vector to get my prediction.

Comment: You don't need to play with the model signature. At the same documentation there is one section called "Get predictions from the export model" that shows you how to format the data for prediction, how to run the prediction and an example of how the results will return

Comment: In this documentation, it's only using docker, and get the prediction through a json dump into a curl request. I should be able to make model prediction through infer.infer([input_vector] directly locally and replicate the model server behaviour I think.

Comment: that's what I said on the original answer -- it is not possible to import the savedmodel using TensorFlow... you must use the modelserver, via docker, as the documentation describes. I've never tried that, but maybe you can load the container image, run a shell on it and check how it does the inference... then possibly you can do that manually too.